# How to find nonzero pixels in specific territory in Mat

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I want to find nonzero pixels with `findNonZero` function in specific place, not the whole Mat.

In the picture posted below, I find the teritory of white patches with `findContours` function. Later, I invert the image posted below with `bitwise_not` function and I need to find the places of pixels of those black patterns seperately for each white patch. **How can I do that?** For each white patch there should be a Mat or Array with black pixel coordinates.

[image]

**My current approach is** to find the contours of the white patches and draw them all each into seperate Mats. Then, find the coordinates of white patch white pixels with `findNonZero`, mix the image with black patterns and with for loop check whether the pixel, which was white, now is black. Put the coordinates of those pixels in a List and later do other things... But this method is neither smart and simple, nor efficient.

**Is there a possibility to do it much simplier and more efficiently? Like being able to find `nonZero` pixels inside the contours?**

Comment: Question not clear enough, Can you elaborate expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR I think the OP wants to FindNonZero pixels with Mask! At present OpenCV does not support any Mask for this operation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Here is a sample implementation! Please use this!

```
void findNonZero( InputArray _src, InputArray _Mask, OutputArray _idx )
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    Mat msk = _Mask.getMat();
    CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_8UC1 );
    CV_Assert( src.size() == msk.size());

    int n = countNonZero(src);
    if( n == 0 )
    {
        _idx.release();
        return;
    }
    if( _idx.kind() == _InputArray::MAT && !_idx.getMatRef().isContinuous() )
        _idx.release();
    _idx.create(n, 1, CV_32SC2);
    Mat idx = _idx.getMat();
    CV_Assert(idx.isContinuous());
    Point* idx_ptr = idx.ptr<Point>();

    for( int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++ )
    {
        const uchar* bin_ptr = src.ptr(i);
        const uchar* msk_ptr = msk .ptr(i);
        for( int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++ )
            if( bin_ptr[j] && msk_ptr[j])
                *idx_ptr++ = Point(j, i);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    string sFileNameEx="F:\\Balaji\\Image Samples\\Test.jpg";
    size_t lastindex = sFileNameEx.find_last_of("."); 
    String sFileName = sFileNameEx.substr(0, lastindex); 
    bool bSaveImages=true;

    Mat mSrc_Gray,mSrc_Mask,mResult_Bgr;

    mSrc_Gray= imread(sFileNameEx,0);
    mSrc_Mask= Mat(mSrc_Gray.size(),CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
    cvtColor(mSrc_Gray,mResult_Bgr,COLOR_GRAY2BGR);


    if(mSrc_Gray.empty())
    {
        cout<<"[Error]! Invalid Input Image";
        return 0;
    }

    threshold(mSrc_Gray,mSrc_Gray,10,255,THRESH_BINARY);
    imshow("mSrc_Gray",mSrc_Gray);
```

[image]

```
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    /// Find contours
    findContours( mSrc_Gray.clone(), contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        if(contourArea(contours[i])>500)
        {
            drawContours(mSrc_Mask,contours,i,Scalar(255),-1);
        }       
    }

    //May be further Filtering like erode needed? 
    imshow("mSrc_Mask",mSrc_Mask);
```

[image]

```
    vector<Point> locations;   // output, locations of non-zero pixels

    findNonZero(mSrc_Gray,mSrc_Mask,locations);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++ )
    {
        circle(mResult_Bgr,locations[i],1,Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    }
    imshow("mResult_Bgr",mResult_Bgr);
```

[image]

```
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not get this one: `findNonZero(mSrc_Gray,mSrc_Mask,locations);`, because in any documentation and in the OpenCV for Java (which I do use for this task) there is no function to find nonzeros with tree parameters. How you are able to use this?

Comment: Like i said before! OpenCV doesn't have the Mask support for findNonZero function! But it is very easy to implement one like in the code above!

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly did not see the function name above. Thanks